# Portforwarding Combine Several Ports

Tags: router, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi

I got a Raspberry Pi at A.A.A.B in my local network and I have set up a DMZ on my router so that any incoming traffic that comes to my router gets redirected to my Raspberry Pi which I can connect via NO-IP adress.

The problem is that I want to set up portforwarding since I got several services running on my Pi like SSH, torrent webgui, webalbum, etc.

I had this already done before long time ago, but I forgot a bit the syntax and cant get to set it up.

Router Help says:

> The Application allows you to do port forwarding, but only have the ports open when data flowing out of the trigger ports. When a program sends data out on outgoing ports called trigger ports, the device then allows incoming data on the open ports specified in your port triggering configuration.

1.Trigger Port Start

> Specify the start port on the device that would trigger the device to open ports for incoming data.

2. Trigger Port End

> Specify the end port on the device that would trigger the device to open ports for incoming data.
>
> You can enter a port number the same as the trigger port start or enter a larger port number to specify a port range.

3.Trigger Traffic Protocol Type

> Select the trigger traffic type.
>
> Open Port
>
> Specify all the ports to be opened. It's content could be:
>
> A single port only.
>
> A port range only. Start open port number and end port number should be separated by "-" .
>
> Combined several single port and several port ranges. Each single port or port range should be separated by "," .
>
> Open Traffic Protocol Type
>
> Select the open traffic type.

These are the fields:

[image: screen]

I think this is the syntax `1`-`7999`, `8001`-`9090`, `9092`-`65535`.

But each time I want to add it gives me an error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got it solved on my own. I knew I could since I have done it before.

It should look like:

- **Trigger Port Start:** 1
- **Trigger Port end:** 65355

Open Port (This is the one that I should have changed): `1`-`7999`, `8001`-`9090`, `9092`-`65355`.